# The Polytopal Sperner Lemma

Tags: combinatorics

In this paper https://www.math.hmc.edu/~su/papers.dir/supersperner.pdf it was proven that "Any Sperner labelling of a triangulation T of an $(n,d)$ - polytope $P$ must contain at least $n$ - $d$ full cells." I was wondering whether we can prove that at least a certain amount of different permutations of full cells must appear? For example, in the case of a $(8,3)$ - polytope, can we prove that more than half of the permutations of the full cells must appear (a cell labeled $(1,2,3,4)$ and another labeled $(1,2,3,5)$ and so on)? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the paper carefully I see that the answer to my question is that different permutations of full triangles must exist. For example, in the $(8,3)$ - polytope at least five triangles with different permutations must exist. This is because a full nerve graph, the concept of which can be found in the paper, was proved by the authors to exist.